# como faço para retornar dois horários usando a função COUNT(*)

Tags: php, mysql

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS contador, hora_efetivada FROM minha_tabela WHERE status=2`

Eu tenho um contador que retorna o valor total de status 2 no banco, porém na minha coluna de nome `hora_efetivada` há diversos horários. Como eu faço para o meu `select` retornar o primeiro horário e o último horário?

Por exemplo:

```
|status| hora_efetivada
| 2    | 13:10
| 2    | 13:12
| 2    | 12:01
| 2    | 08:03
| 2    | 18:03
| 2    | 13:03
```

Meu SELECT retornaria `COUNT = 6` e os dois horários (`08:03` e `13:13`).

Terei que implementar de uma outra forma?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS contador, MIN(hora_efetivada) as primeiro_horario, MAX(hora_efetivada) as ultimo_horario FROM minha_tabela WHERE status=2` Desde que a coluna seja do tipo *TIME*, caso contrario será necessario fazer um `CAST`.

Comment: `SELECT 
       COUNT(STATUS) AS TOTAL,
       STATUS,
       SELECT SUBSTRING(HORA_EFETIVADA,-3);
    FROM
       MINHA_TABELA
    GROUP BY
       STATUS`

Answer (score 7):

Se o campo for de um tipo DATE/TIME você pode usar **MIN** e **MAX** para retornar o menor e o maior valor de um grupo de resultados.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS contador, 
  MIN(hora_efetivada) as primeiro_horario,     
  MAX(hora_efetivada) as ultimo_horario 
FROM minha_tabela WHERE status=2
```

Se a coluna for do tipo VARCHAR por exemplo, é necessário fazer um ***CAST***

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS contador, 
  MIN(STR_TO_DATE(hora_efetivada, '%h:%i')) as primeiro_horario,     
  MAX(STR_TO_DATE(hora_efetivada, , '%h:%i')) as ultimo_horario 
FROM minha_tabela WHERE status=2
```

Answer (score 4):

Basta dar um `MIN` e um `MAX` nos valores, e usar `DATE_FORMAT` para formatá-los:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(MIN(hora), "%H:%i") as menor_hora,
    DATE_FORMAT(MAX(hora), "%H:%i") as maior_hora
FROM minha_tabela
WHERE status = 2
```